# MVC 5 - Use String as a View rendered with a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am displaying 1..N "tiles" of listings from a database.  Each "tile" has several attributes such as ID, Name, description.  Each description will show differently depending on various user properties such as country and status (in my app, there are 10 different user properties).

Example description (stored like this in the db):

```
@if(Model.status == "eligible") {
    <p>Complete this activity to earn @(Model.country == "US" ? "1,000" : "2,000") points</p>
} else {
    <p>You are not eligible to complete this activity<p>
}
```

The Model is always the same (based on the user logged in) but each description will be different depending on how the admin wants to leverage each of 10 available properties.  Another example (stored like this in the db):

```
@if(Model.status == "eligible") 
{
    <p>Complete this activity to earn points</p>
    @if(Model.isManager) 
    {
        <p><a href="@Url.Action("ActivityReport","Reports")">Check usage Reports</a></p>
    }
} 
@if(Model.hasExternalAccount) {
    <p>As soon as you complete your activity, your points will automatically be available in your external account!<p>
} else {
    <p>Be sure to sign up for an external account so you can use your points to shop for great things</p>
}
```

These descriptions can be updated/edited by an admin at any point in time, so the descriptions can change at runtime.

The trouble I'm running into is using a Custom VirtualPathProvider/Virtual file doesn't allow me to pass a string into the "open" method of the virtual file in order to have that custom view for each item.  I've seen several examples where the file data is pulled from a database, an xml file, or whatever...but none of them allow me to pass in a string.

Example (uses an xml file):https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2

Any suggestions?  I'm trying to avoid the potential of having 50+ database calls to get the activity descriptions since I'm already looping through the dataset on the front end to display everything already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could easily solve your problem by using [Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

If you check the link I sent you, please take a look at passing objects into the partial view and that should get you in the right direction.

---

I'm not clear if your "description" data or view is HTML. In such a case, then `@Html.Raw()` could be your good friend.

Comment: Yes and no - the "description" field is stored in the database and is editable by the admin.  So the view can change from one minute to the next.

Comment: The way I interpreted your question was that the view model does not change (ie. only the property values change, but same model) and you were looking for a way to pass this view model into something like a partial view? The sentence that I gave me that impression was , quote: *"I'm trying to avoid the potential of having 50+ database calls since I'm already looping through the dataset on the front end"* -- I assumed you have 50 view models ready to go, just needed a view to go with it.

Comment: I have a single Model with 50+ different views.  Each view can be changed on the fly by the admin and is stored in the database.

Comment: Do you mean you have HTML stored in the database? Then why not`@Html.Raw()`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have made Razor View code editable by non-programmers by storing the view content in a virtual file system that is editable by some other mechanism.  It seems the reason for making the View code editable by management is so that they can change the business logic without the need to change the program.

The code about points for US and non-US countries is "business logic".  Finding business logic in a view is an indicator that the MVC pattern is not being followed.

MVC is not just a technology framework from Microsoft to make web applications based on .NET.  It's a design pattern that separates concerns about Controlling (who can access what, what can be done), Viewing (presentation layer, as CSS is to HTML) and Modeling (providing data to the view).  I think the Model layer is the hardest to understand conceptually and I found it very useful to read about MVC and even MVVM to learn what the model can and should do.  The model layer is much more than just a database object.

Supporting variable business logic is a requirement of your software and the typical way of handing that is for your MVC program to provide a management interface for creating, updating and deleting that content.  The logic needs to be re imagined as content.  Take the points variation again as an example.  This could be stored in a table that maps countries to points.

It might seem impossible given the complexity (10 variables) but let me demonstrate a brute-force approach that at least proves it's possible:  If you have 10 variables on which to base the content, you could have an 11 column table.  The first 10 columns specify the variables and the 11th column is editable by management.  This is basically a [truth-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

Now, a flat table like this leverages none of the benefits of a RDBMS, so I certainly wouldn't advocate that as an actual approach.  A truth table can be useful as a tool to expose requirements at the design stage.  For example, you might quickly find that where `status != "eligible"` then the description should always be "You are not eligible to complete this activity".  Armed with that information you can certainly come up with a simpler design.  Here is where you decide what can safely be hard-coded and what must be editable by management.

Beyond that as a broad approach, it's worth mentioning a couple of other things that can assist in this kind of project:

- Database views can be really powerful for assembling exactly what you need for a MVC view.  Where you raised a concern about looping through the data set from the front end, this is further evidence that the current design pattern is problematic.  It is entirely possible for a single query to return the complete, assembled description for a given MVC View.
- `String.Format()` can be very useful for situations like the US points variation in your first string.